# Responsive content with height limited to screen size

Tags: html, css

For the last couple of days I am working in a simple step by step tutorial layout (html/css), and I cannot make it responsive and limited to screen size at same time.

Here is what I have so far and what I am trying to do:

[image]

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div id="tutorial">
  <h1>Step 2 - Title</h1>
  <h3>Second step description / instructions</h3>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="ctrls">
      <img src="images/prev.png">
      <img src="images/stop.png">
      <img src="images/next.png">
    </div>
    <div id="image">
      <img src="images/step2.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="controls">
    <div class="btn prev">
      <img src="images/btn_prev.png">
    <div class="btn next">
      <img src="images/btn_next.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body {
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: Arial;
}
#tutorial {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #FFFFCC;
}
h1 {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
}
#content {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 16px;
    height: calc(100vh - 220px);
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
}
#content #image {
    position: relative;
}
#content #image img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
#content #ctrls {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    display: table;
    padding: 2px;
}
#content #ctrls img {
    width: 48px;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
}
#controls {
    display: table;
    margin: 4px auto;
}
#controls .btn {
    margin-top: 6px;
    float: left;
}
#controls .prev {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
#controls .next {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
#controls .off {
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
}
#controls .btn img {
    border: 0;
}
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this variant. I rewrote your code a bit...
https://codepen.io/opmasan/pen/jObdmdd

```
:root {
  --header-height: 100px;
  --footer-height: 200px;

}

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body {
    font-family: Arial;
}
#tutorial {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #FFFFCC;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
h1 {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
}
#content {
    display: flex;
    padding: 16px;
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
}
#content #image {
    position: relative;   
}
#content #image img {
    height: calc(100vh - var(--header-height) - var(--footer-height));
    max-height:100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
#content #ctrls {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #3AE2CE;
}
#controls {
    display: flex;
    margin: 4px auto;
}
#controls .btn {
    margin-top: 6px;
    float: left;
}
#controls .prev {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
#controls .next {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
#controls .off {
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much Alexander!

Comment: The only strange behavier I saw is when the browser window is maximized, the image get smaller (cut) than the original size... but I don't think this will be a problem.

Comment: Please, do you know how to make image responsible when screen width is smaller than original image width? I'd like the image to get proportionally smaller... Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this option will be better https://codepen.io/opmasan/pen/JjYxJgv

Comment: Thank you for helping me! Success!

Answer (score 0):

Remove  `height: calc(100vh - 220px);` from your content div.

Then, Just declare the div size and make the image size 100%.

```
#image{
height:200px;
width:200px;
}

#image img{
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, but it need to be responsible. I can't define the div or the image size. I need it to fit in the screen until maximum height do not get higher then screen height.

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/opmasan/pen/JjYxJgv
This variant with object-fit: contain and some fixes in html will be better:

```
#content #image img {
  object-fit: contain;
}
```